# Add DLL reference to standalone ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, dll, assemblies, dllimport, npgsql

I want to reference a dll file in a standalone aspx page. 
The project structure is:

```
Project

      -BIN

          -Npgsql.dll

      -Data

          -Group

                -Forms

                      -Sheet1.aspx
```

Tried using

```
<%@ Assembly Name="assemblyname" %>
<%@ Assembly Src="pathname" %>
```

but no success.

Comment: The aspx page belongs to a project, that's where you add references.

Comment: @DavidG done that by using Nuget Console...

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: the page is not loading, while coding it does not gives any syntax error, IntelliSense works fine. But when I use Npgsql  it gives "page can’t be found" otherwise it works fine.